# How can I add a validation error in before_save association callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models: The Discount has and belongs to many Businsses.

I want to validate that a Discount always have at least one business, together with another condition (for example `active?`). I tried the following:

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses,
    before_remove: :validate_publish_status

  def validate_publish_status(*arg)
    if active? && businesses.count == 0
      errors[:active] << 'discount with no business'
    end
  end
end
```

However this does not work (no validation errors raised) and I realized that this is probably because it is only a callback, not a validation. How can I code it so I can use the `errors` like I do I custom validation?

The controller action I have (for ajax):

```
  def remove
    @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
    if @business.in? @discount.businesses
      @discount.businesses.delete(@business)
    end
    render json: @business.as_json(only: [:id, :type, :name, :address],
                                   methods: [:city_name, :country_name]).
      merge(paths: paths_for(@discount, @business))
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid # even tried the generic Exception
    respond_to do |f|
      f.json { render json: {error: $!.message}, status: 403 }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could be your syntax on the before_remove callback or what's happening in the validation method itself.  You also might want to add some debug code in the callback method to see if it's even making in there.

*Note that the transaction will only be stopped if an exception is raised in the callback method.  Since this is the case, you'll probably want to handle the exception logic in your controller to re-render the action:

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses, :before_remove => :validate_publish_status

  def validate_publish_status(*args)
   if yyy? && businesses.count == 0
    errors.add(:yyy,'discount with no business')
    raise "Unable to remove business."
   end
  end

end
```

controller gist:

```
  def update
    @company.find(params[:id])
    if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      ...
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  rescue
    render :action=>'edit'
  end
```

Note the [Association Callback Documentation.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks)

Comment: thanks, I did check and it ran through the method. If I `raise 'error'` it would raise the error as expected.

Comment: I updated the answer with some more info.  You'll want to raise an exception in the callback to stop the transaction.  In doing that you'll probably want to do some exception handling in the controller to re-render the action.

Comment: You can also return false to halt the execution. "The whole callback chain is wrapped in a transaction. If any before callback method returns exactly false or raises an exception, the execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued; after callbacks can only accomplish that by raising an exception." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution

Comment: @foo - I thought the exact same thing but apparently the association callbacks only halt with an exception.  Wondering if this is a Rails bug actually. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks

Comment: @miked: Ah, I din't know about that, another new knowledge. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [validates](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) method with `:presence => true` for this.

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses
  validates :businesses, :presence => true
end
```

Using `:presence => true` on an association validator will ensure that at least one member of the association exists.

Comment: thanks but I need to check one additional field in that validation (the yyy? part). So I must write a custom validation.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide a better description of what exactly you are looking for then? You don't say anything about yyy or what it's supposed to be in your description, and it's really not clear from your code what you're trying to do with yyy.

Comment: my bad, I have rephrased yyy? to active? But it can be any arbitrary expression which evaluates to boolean.

Comment: It is a very useful tip.