# How to change validation error messages for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Document` class, with `has_many :fields`. Each Field object has a `name` attribute.

When I validate the Document and the associated Fields, I get the following validation error message for each invalid Field association:

```
Fields is invalid.
```

This is a very useless error message. Instead, I want it to say:

```
Field '<value of the name attribute>' is invalid.
```

For example:

```
Field 'subject' is invalid.
Field 'date' is invalid.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. no good answer so far.

So I solved it by myself by replacing association error message with detail error message:

Create a concern file `app/models/concerns/association_error_detail_concern.rb`:

```rb
    module AssociationErrorDetailConcern
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    
      included do
        after_validation :replace_association_error_message
      end
    
      class_methods do
        def association_names
          @association_names ||= self.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)
        end
      end
    
   
      def replace_association_error_message
 
        # Gets the intersection between this class's associations and the instance's associations that have validation errors
        associations_with_errors = self.errors.keys & self.class.association_names
    
        associations_with_errors.each do |association_name|
          next unless self.errors[association_name]
          self.errors.delete(association_name)
          Array.wrap(public_send(association_name)).each do |record|
            record.errors.each do |attribute, error|
              self.errors.add(:"#{association_name}.#{attribute}", error)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

then include it in your model:

```
class Shop::Product < ApplicationRecord
  include AssociationErrorDetailConcern
  ...
end
```

Then let's talk about translations of these attributes.

Rails will automatically take those defined in the associated model's translations:

```
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      associated_model_name:
        attribute_name: 'Foo'
```

However, the need may arise so that this attribute has a different translation when validated in the context of it's association. Instead of just showing `Email is required`, which works fine when you are validating a User, you might want to show something like `Poster's e-mail is required` when validating a `Post` that `belongs_to :user`.

With the above concern, since the errors will be added to a key `:user.email`, Rails will find the `activerecord.attributes.user.email` translation, but it will also look first in `activerecord.attributes.post/user.email`, like so:

```
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post/user:
        email: 'Foo'
```

This gives you the ultimate flexibility on translating these attributes, depending on the context where they are being validated.

If you want to understand how Rails find these keys, take a look at the `translation.rb#human_attribute_name`, you'll see it will split the key at the `.` and use that to look for keys in the `.yml` file.

`EDITOR="sublime --wait" bundle open activemodel`

Last, but not least, don't forget that Rails will only automatically validate your association if it's a `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` (check the `validate` option on each association type https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

The `belongs_to` and `has_one` have a default `validate: false`, which you can change to `true` or use the `validates_associated`.

In the example above, since it's a Post that `belongs_to :user`, you'd have to add a `validates_associated :user` for instance, otherwise the User's validation wouldn't even run.

Comment: brilliant concern, I just made an enhancement on it so that it works with nested i18n keys

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this has already been asked.

Might be useful looking at this answer:

[How can I add a validation error in before_save association callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061569/how-can-i-add-a-validation-error-in-before-save-association-callbacks)

or the ruby api documentation:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: This isn't about custom validations, it's about customizing the message of a builtin validation on associations.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to customize the auto-validated associations, this is definitely something Rails can enhance. You can however turn off the auto-validation of associations on has_many (but make sure you do validate them manually somehow):

```
has_many :fields, validate: false
```

Then, for example, you can add a generic message manually, like:

```
validates_associated :fields, message: "ARE Invalid."
```

But be aware that this would replace the message on ALL validations of fields, not just the "is invalid"

If you need a more custom message that includes values of invalid names, you'll have to do the  manual validation in a before_save hook

Answer (score 0):

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      cricket: #model name 
        game: "" # attribute name ( can be game_id)
    errors:
      models:
        cricket: # model name
          attributes:
            game: # attribute name
              required: "Error message has been changed."
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting value in en.yml & using it in error message worked for me but I have to provide the static message too that needs to be appended after every field name. I found a easy way to do this, after doing this I don't have to put anything in en.yml. Use instead

validates :field, validates_associated: {message: "%{model} is invalid"}

you can try below keywords:

- model
- attribute
- value